# Issues with slicer creating gaps with surfaces that are not in the model

Tags: 3d-models, slicing, creality-ender-2

I have an odd issue with Creality Slicer 4.8 (Cura slicer?)

It wants to cut up my model and add surfaces that do not exist in the model.

These screenshots are without infill or support:

[image: Head displaying cut surface]

[image: layer 824]

[image: layer 821]

Wire mesh view from behind and to the left (Blender)
[image: Blender wire mesh]

I assume that since this model is a base 3D model from a game with the body, clothes, hairstyle, etc put on top, that I have overlooked something which is being interpreted as a surface break. I had a similar problem with the dress and boots, which I solved by tediously removing the inner details.

I have removed the back part of the "skull" and the top of the neck, trying to closed any gaps.

[image: solid and wireframe - blender]

[STL](http://test.stevnsvig.com/priestess_4_8.stl)

How do I fix this issue?

I am printing on a Creality Ender 2.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with the model, not the slicer. If from Blender, the chance that there are normals incorrect or hidden surfaces present are high. You should fix the model first. Please use the search function, there are multiple questions related to such issues. Usually it is recommended to use Netfabb to fix it, this may help your search for a solution.

Comment: Why are you still using Cura 4.8 and not yet Cura 5.5? It has some major improvements. Perhaps using that instead can already fix your issue.

Comment: @BobOrtiz  I just downloaded the latest version I could from creality

Comment: Try https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura/#downloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Some Surfaces are likely inverted - which needs to be made visible.

To see that in blender, you need to turn on "surface normals". The blue spikes should go out of the surfaces, showing the item is properly aligned.

[image: position of surface normals in edit mode]

To flip those surfaces and make all show into the same direction, follow for example this answer [Slicer is adding additional floor bed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11013/slicer-is-adding-additional-floor-bed/14309#14309) - the relevant part for it here:

> - Enter Edit mode
> - `A` to select everything
> - `ALT` + `N` to recalculate normals

Another way to get the normals displayed is:

> - `N` then under `Mesh Display > Normals` hook `Faces`